# Procedimiento de Oracle a Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, plsql

tengo el siguiente caso.

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en plsql y lo necesito pasar a mysql, pero le problema es que tengo dudas con relación a las funciones o la forma de usar procedimientos parecidos de oracle en mysql.

```
 FOR i IN REVERSE 1 .. LENGTH(v_numero_al) LOOP
  IF k > p_basemax THEN
  k := 2;
  END IF;
  v_numero_aux := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(v_numero_al,i,1));
  v_total := v_total + (v_numero_aux * k);
  k := k + 1;
 END LOOP;
```

Por ejemplo una duda seria de como hacer el ciclo for y el reverse en mysql.

Saludos Cordiales a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar con la estructura **repeat** de MySQL

```
SET @ciclos = 1
REPEAT
 SET @ciclos =+ 1
UNTIL @ciclos > 10
END REPEAT;
```